# Reflect updated value changes during inline-edit functionality Angular 4 --

Tags: angular, html, typescript, inline-editing

my problem --

I have a field for customer address and I am displaying the value for it by retrieving it from db and binding it. Now, I have tried to implement inline-edit functionality. When a user clicks on the address value, it turns into a textbox that is still showing the original value. Now after editing/changing some text, as the user clicks out of the texbox or 'tabs' away, it reverts back to the original label field again, but still showing only the old value and not the newly updated value. Of course I am updating the value in DB and it is perfectly updating. But I would like is to show the newly updated value bound to the label instead of the old one. And one way for this - is to call the retrieve and bind code all over again. WHICH I SIMPLY WANT TO AVOID. IT MAKES NO SENSE.

So, what's the trick? How can this be done? 
I'll post some of the relevant code so that you get an idea.

. some html markup

```
    <tr style="margin-top:22px">
            <td>Address (Residential): </td>
            <td>
                <div *ngIf="ed3">
                    <input type="text" id="address_txt" (blur)="setval3($event.target.value)" [value]="this.addressVar" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="!ed3">
                    <div title="Click to Edit" class="inline-edit" id="addr_div" (click)="edit3(val)" (focus)="edit3(val)">{{this.addressVar}}</div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

. some of the TS code

```
    private ed3: boolean = false;
    public addressVar: any = '';

    edit3(value: any) {
    if (this.disabled) {
        return;
    }

    this.ed3 = true;
}

    setval3(value: any) {
    this.ed3 = false;
    this.fieldtoUpdate = 'customer_resaddress';
    var body =
        {
            id: this.cus_id,
            new_val: value,
            field: this.fieldtoUpdate
        }
    var _Headers = new Headers();
    _Headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    public ngOnInit() {

   //stuff I am doing to fetch and bind from DB
   //as you can see, I am using the variables now

    this.http.post('api/SampleData/GetCustomerAllDetails', JSON.stringify(body), { headers: _Headers })
        .subscribe(result => {
            this.cObjx = result.json() as CustomerD;
            this.addressVar = this.cObjx.customer_resaddress == null ? 'Not specified' : this.cObjx.customer_resaddress;
            this.phoneVar = this.cObjx.customer_phone;
            this.mobileVar = this.cObjx.customer_mobile == null ? 'Not specified' : this.cObjx.customer_mobile;
            this.officephnVar = this.cObjx.customer_officephone == null ? 'Not specified' : this.cObjx.customer_officephone;
        },
        error => console.error(error));


} 
    this.http.post('api/SampleData/UpdateCustomerDetails/values', JSON.stringify(body), { headers: _Headers })
        .take(1)
        .subscribe((response: any) => {
            if (response.success) {
                console.log('Details updated!');
            }
            else {
                console.log('Unable to update details!');
            }
        })
}
```

As you can understand, calling the bind function again is not my aim. I am trying to avoid that. From some articles I read on this type of scenario, it appears I have to use some kind of third [temporary control] which would basically display the new value. Or maybe I am wrong with that and there's a better idea. I really need some guidance on this. Quite confused!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are using two-way binding?

Instead of this:

```
[value]="this.addressVar"
```

Consider using this:

```
[(ngModel)]="this.addressVar"
```

Comment: hi Deborah @deborahk, I am going to try this out.
I'll report back with updates, thanks as always;

Comment: yes, using ngModel in place of [value] solves it just fine. The newly entered value reflects immediately cuz of the two way binding.  @deborahk thanks,

Answer (score 2):

If it was me, I'd bind the text box to a TS variable such as:

```
let addressVar = cObjx.customer_resaddress==null?'Not specified':cObjx.customer_resaddress;
```

Two way binding should make sure that updates properly during your edit functions, and if the database is updating properly, when you look at it later, the initial binding will continue to be correct.

If you have multiple people editing the same information, that would present a problem, but that doesn't look like the case here.

Comment: hi, yes, multiple persons editing won't be needed in my case here; So I suppose I can bind both the fields, my label/div as well as the input box to the variable addressVar and this way, it is gonna reflect the newly updated value spontaneously. right?

Comment: thanks @Michael yes I will implement it; but just for additional knowledge/option - is there another way that can be implemented as a more robust maybe?
thanks,

Comment: Hi @MichaleMcPherson, yes I tried as you suggested; but it's still not showing the newly entered values. Only the old bound values. I have bound it to the variable instead of directly binding from the result response. I have updated my code listing too, so you can take a look if whatever I did was okay.....       so what next??

Comment: I'd review @DeborahK's thought below, and make sure that your two way binding is working properly. If you could pare down your code enough for us to paste it into an IDE/JSFiddle and run/debug it, that would also help.

Comment: hi Michael,
okkay I will supply more of the code snippets so that I a fiddle can be made, no problem. Meanwhile let me just try out Deborah's @deborahk snippet, I have a hunch it is gonna solve the issue; using ngModel instead of [value].